# Error de carga de recursos con Laravel

Tags: html, css

acabo de subir mi proyecto en laravel 6 a un hosting compartido, el sitio carga imagenes pero no me carga recursos como el css ni encuentra las rutas, ya modifique el env a pro y le di la direccion de mi proyecto

gracias
este es el dominio     macmetrologia.com.co

y esto sale al cargar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pregunta inocente: ¿Cómo crees que podemos resolver tu caso sin código mostrado, ni datos de configuración ni datos del servidor ni características del mismo y sin una url al menos para ver qué errores se han generado? Revisa estas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: ya edite la pregunta, gracias

Comment: Puedes agregar por ejemplo el código de como invocas a tus css en tu vista

Comment: tu problema es que tienes un punto luego del css: `dominio/css./font-awesome.css` lo mismo en `dominio/css./app.css`

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset("css./app.css")}}">   asi defini la ruta del css en entorno local

Comment: correcto amigo muchas gracias, era el punto, ahora lo que me falta es que encuentre las rutas porque en entorno local todo iba bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reemplaza:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset("css./app.css")}}">
```

Por:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset("css/app.css")}}">
```

Detalle: El punto antes del slash o barra inclinada, genera una ruptura de los recursos.

Comment: gracias, se soluciono la carga de recursos pero sigo sin poder acceder a las rutas

Comment: me alegra bro :D masbien, creo que esa es otra pregunta que puedes formular en el sitio, recuerda incluir el código necesario para que la comunidad pueda reproducir tu escenario

Comment: dale haré la pregunta correspondiente, nuevamente gracias

Comment: un placer colaborar con la comunidad, éxitos con el desarrollo, sigue adelante, vas por buen camino :D

Comment: @fredyfx para que la etiqueta de Laravel o php si el problema esta a nivel de la ruta en el html?

Comment: El problema es del framework que esta usando: Laravel, ergo, PHP, no es un simple `href` o un `src` de HTML, lo conversamos en el chat ¿te parece?

Comment: solo era una mera duda fredyfx, además no cuento con el tiempo ahorita

Comment: vale hermano, espero me haya dejado entender :D